# Visual Studio unwanted breakpoint on first line

Tags: visual-studio, breakpoints

I'm getting this strange behavior when I launch a program without selecting "Step Into new instance". It launches the program as if I had, requiring me to manually hit F5.

If I explicitly select to step into the new instance, I have to hit F5 twice before it proceeds. I've tried restarting, and messing around with the exception options. It's not an exception. And no, there isn't a breakpoint defined on the first line.

Has anyone seen this before?

Comment: What version of Visual Studio?  What language(s)?  Is it just for that particular project, or does it do the same for all projects (including a new, "hello world" type of project?

Comment: VS2010, just for this solution I've just checked out. There's two projects that I normally start, and they both do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to take some guesses here:

Try closing the solution then moving or renaming the `*.suo` file for this solution (the `*.suo` file keeps some information like breakpoint settings and certain UI states - it probably shouldn't be in version control if it is). Reopen the solution and see if it behaves any better.

If not, try the same process, but rename/move any `*.vcxproj.user` files (which have per-user project settings, and also probably shouldn't be in version control).  If you're using some other project type than C++, there will be slightly different names - but I think they all end in `*.user`.  There might also be `*.vcxproj.<user name>.user` files that you'd want to handle similarly.

If one of these turn out to solve the problem, you might want to look at the file to see if there's something that would tell you what the problem was (`.vcxproj` is quite readable XML, the `*.suo` file is some undocumented binary format, so you probably wouldn't be able to identify anything in there).